# WCF TCP Protocol

Tags: asp.net, wcf, tcp

I want to host a WCF service with TCP Protocol.

I can host the service using IIS or Windows Service.

I need to know what port I need to open for this service for it to be accessible by client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting a WCF service using TCP/IP in IIS can be fairly involved and messy - especially on IIS6.

If you host it in your own Windows Service, you have total control over what address and port your service should use. Whatever port you decide to use needs to be accessible from the outside world. There's no limitation on what port you can use (other than avoiding the standard ports like 21, 25 and so on - use something above 1000, preferably).

Comment: Yes, the port you need to open is the port you choose the WCF service to use(normally configured in your app.config)

Comment: Can a WCF service even BE hosted in IIS 6 if it uses TCP?  My understanding was no, but I found this question when searching for a way to do it...

Comment: @James B: no, IIS6 supports HTTP only. If you only have IIS6, you need to self-host a WCF service in order to get TCP/IP as protocol.